# Laravel 5.2 SaveMany creates blank record

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I have ManyToMany relation in Laravel 5.2:

**User model:**

```
public function Lessons(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lesson')->withPivot('created_by', 'number_of_lessons','id');
}
```

However, I want to save multiple lessons in pivot table like this:

```
$output = [];
$output[] = $this->RidingCourses()->wherePivot('created_by',1)->first()->pivot->number_of_lessons = 200;
$output[] = $this->RidingCourses()->wherePivot('created_by',2)->first()->pivot->number_of_lessons = 200;
$this->RidingCourses()->saveMany([$output]);
```

Pivot records are getting updated, but there are also created two blank records in the pivot table. So my question is, **how can I correctly save multiple ManyToMany related models?**

Answer (score 0):

Check 'created_by', 'number_of_lessons','id' are fillable in your model?
Are you trying to update the existing records?

If these columns are fillable and still facing the same issue than use save or create method in place of saveMany.

I was facing the same issue and put same question in Laracast too but not get any response yet.

I think this is a bug in Laravel 5.2.

Comment: I would not worry about mass assignment issue here - everything gets updated as it should. The most crucial question for me is how to update multiple related models without creating new blank records. It can be done by DB:insert, but I hope there is an eloquent way for this.